# Including strings as parameters for a function chosen for .setAttribute to a button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to pass along a string as a value for a button's onclick function using setAttribute. I am getting the error that "add is not defined" when I click on the button and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    var AddButton = document.createElement("button");
    var AddString = "add";
    var SectorString = "1_1";
    AddButton.setAttribute("onclick",'AddOrDeleteDiv(AddString,SectorString)');





   function AddOrDeleteDiv(AddString, SectorString) {
//code 
}
```

Comment: Try encapsulating `"add"` with another set of quotes: `"'add'"`... not 100% sure but that might work

Comment: wrap the arguments with single quotes and replace the old single quotes with double quotes. `AddButton.setAttribute("onclick","AddOrDeleteDiv('"+add+"','"+SectorString+"')");`

Comment: don't use the onclick-attribute, use the property: `AddButton.onclick = function(){ AddOrDeleteDiv("add", "1_1") }` and take a look at [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use content attribute event handlers! Use event listeners instead:

```
var addButton = document.createElement("button");
var addString = "add";
var sectorString = "1_1";
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addOrDeleteDiv(addString, sectorString);
});
function addOrDeleteDiv(addString, sectorString) {
  //code 
}
```

Comment: listener on what ? :) you missed to add event name

Comment: @MarkoMackic Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well js is known for not having nice methods for string joining and please try to use function parameter names not same as global variable names, it's not a nice thing to do.

```
var AddButton = document.createElement("button");
var AddString = "add";
var SectorString = "1_1";
AddButton.setAttribute("onclick",'AddOrDeleteDiv(' + JSON.stringify(AddString) + ',' + JSON.stringify(SectorString) + ')');


function AddOrDeleteDiv(addStr, secStr) {
//code 
}
```

or as @Thomas said you could use acutual javascript event handler like , not modifying attributes to assign event handler

```
AddButton.onclick = function(){AddOrDeleteDiv(AddString,SectorString);}
```

Comment: You have to `JSON.stringify()` the values of `AddString` and `SectorString` to inject them into a piece of code.

Comment: Don't you need single quotes to warp the arguments? Example `(\'' + AddString + '\',`

Comment: @Thomas no I don't

Comment: If you're just wrappin the Strings in quotes you might get into trouble as soon as the strings contain the same quotes, or a backslash, or a line break. This means you need proper escaping. JSON.stringify is the best way to convert a String into some correct formatted string-literal(-string). Like if it was built for this task.

Comment: @Thomas well you're correct, but anyways, the attributes modification is unnecessary overhead to this problem. Anyway's I'll correct it

Comment: `'AddOrDeleteDiv(' + JSON.stringify(AddString) + ',' + JSON.stringify(SectorString) + ')'`

Comment: the outer quotes are just annotation/delimiters by the console, to annotate that the object it is showing is a String. Like an Array starts in the console with a `[` although the Array doesn't contain any square brackets.  check charAt(1), there is no second `"` in the String, or alert() the string instead of showing it in the console. map the chars one by one if you have to. It's just bad formatting through the console; the String is fine.

Comment: I was confused. my mistake